# firewatch Parallax effect with another div above with content

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, parallax

I'm struggling to find a way to set the parallax effect with the mountains... on the top of the page and the div with the content of the website below it. I have tried with z-index and position but I haven't reached it.

Thanks for your replies.

```
<div id="parallax">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="30" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p0.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="18" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p1.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="12" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p2.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="8" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p3.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="6" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p4.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="0" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p6.png">
</div>
<div id="test">
    <font color="red">This is some text!asdfasd</font>
</div>

document.querySelectorAll('.scene').forEach((elem) => {

    const modifier = elem.getAttribute('data-modifier')

    basicScroll.create({
        elem: elem,
        from: 0,
        to: 519,
        direct: true,
        props: {
            '--translateY': {
                from: '0',
                to: `${ 10 * modifier }px`
            }
        }
    }).start()

})

body {
    height: 2000px;
    background: black;
}

.scene {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(var(--translateY));
    will-change: transform;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ufcqw2xh/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your overlay div to `position:fixed`

https://jsfiddle.net/zhyeubg8/

**Edit:**
If you want your test div to scroll with the mountains, just move it inside your parallax `div`, give it the same `data-modifier` as the layer you want it to scroll with, and position it with CSS.

```
<div id="parallax">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="30" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p0.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="18" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p1.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="12" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p2.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="8" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p3.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="6" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p4.png">
<img class="scene" data-modifier="0" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p6.png">
<div id="test" class="scene" data-modifier="0">
    <font color="red">This is some text!asdfasd</font>
</div>
</div>
```

```
#test {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ghmo629v/

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I didn't explain correctly the issue. I want to do something like: https://www.firewatchgame.com/. The header with the parallax and all the layers and below all the website content.

Comment: @JavierdelHoyo Don't you need more elements, then?  What part of the firewatch page does your test div represent?

Comment: My text div represent the contect of the web.

Comment: AVAILABLE NOW FOR $19.99 for example

Comment: It is exactly what I asked. But why if a add more divs to the content below test div?. Thanks and sorry for bother you.

Comment: @JavierdelHoyo Just throw everything inside your test div and it will all move together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204988/discussion-between-thingevery-and-javier-del-hoyo).